# JBorder doesn't display right

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jlabel

I have an application that uses a `JLabel` and a `JPanel`. These components have a `MatteBorder`. When the components are created, the border is the default. When I click on the components, I set the border to a different thickness to make a select appearance. The problem comes when I want to unselect and I set the border to another thickness. This time the border is not modified and looks the same.

I'm not seeing what the problem is, because the first modification of the border thickness works fine.

Comment: What is a `JLable`? What is a `MatterBorder`? Where is your code?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue with Border

Comment: Without seeing what you could be doing wrong, we are forced to guess, and usually that doesn't work too well. Why not do as others have suggested and show code. Best if you try to isolate the problem by posting a [minimal compilable code example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Great, but again remember that it will help all involved if your code is compilable and runnable but also is minimal and has no code that is not essential for running and for demonstrating the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might be a hacky approach, try to repaint() the view, sometimes it just glitches.

I read this: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html
when working on my program.